# How to view all warning prompts in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

### When coding, I sometimes get these helpful popups that notifies me when I made a mistake.

[image]

### Is there a place in Android studio where I can get a list of them for a particular project - like a TODO list

(so I dont have to go through each file manually, scrolling, and checking for them)

Comment: try code inspection

Comment: @DivyeshPatel care to provide a screenshot or something? Im not exactly an expert at Android studio

Comment: in studio, open Analyze menu from top. in that menu run Inspect code

Comment: Select the file or folder from the side bar (project view in left side), right click on it, choose Analyze > Inspect Code, After inspecting the code it will come up with warning and possible solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the steps -

1) Click on Analyze > Inspect Code
[image]

2) A dialog will popup, select the required scope [image]

3) The results will be displayed at the bottom panel[image]

Hope this helps